# Can non-special C++ member functions be deleted (or defaulted)?

Tags: c++, c++11

A lot of attention has been received by `= default` and `= delete` with respect to the special members (default constructor, destructor, copy and move). Can `= default` and `= delete` be used with other functions; member functions, free functions and operators etc.?

I can understand that `= default` would probably not be allowed outside the special members; since it is basically saying *use the compiler generated default*. The default would need to be clearly defined before the compiler is able to generate it. As far as I know, only the special members have these pre-defined defaults.

What about `= delete`; it is basically saying that *the function is declared, but the implementation is explicitly not defined*.

- Can `= delete` be used with functions other than the special members?
- What function types can it be used on (members, non-members, operators etc.)?
- Or conversely, where (or when) is `= delete` prohibited from being used? Are there any restrictions on its use?

Comment: _"The function is declared, but the implementation is explicitly not defined"_ is the wrong way of thinking about `=delete`. The function is declared and is inaccessible; attempting to call the function is a compile-time error. The fact that the implementation is not defined is merely a consequence of this, because it wouldn't make sense to implement a function which can't be called.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any function whatsoever can be declared as deleted (using `= delete`). The standard does not impose any restrictions. This is covered by C++11[dcl.fct.def.delete]. It even gives an example of a deleted `operator new`.

Defaulted functions, on the other hand, *are* limited by [dcl.fct.def.default]§1 as follows:

> 1 ... A function that is explicitly defaulted shall
>
> - be a special member function,
> - have the same declared function type (except for possibly differing *ref-qualifiers* and except that in the case of a copy constructor or copy assignment operator, the parameter type may be “reference to
>     non-const `T`”, where `T` is the name of the member function’s class)
>     as if it had been implicitly declared, and
> - not have default arguments.

The "special member functions" referenced in the first bullet point are (as per [special]§1):

- default constructor
- copy constructor
- move constructor
- copy assignment operator
- move assignment operator
- destructor

Comment: I think the next question in this is how well this is supported in the compilers available today. Thanks for the additional references.

Comment: @Niall As far as I know, GCC and Clang support all of C++11 now (GCC since 4.8.1 or similar, Clang around that time as well). MSVC supports this since VS 2013, except for defaulting move functions. I don't know about other compilers; you can always consult their docs.

Comment: Do all default-able members exist by default? Or do they have to be explicitly declared as `= default`? If so, why?

Comment: @anddero That's a separate question worth its own research, and might even be already answered somewhere here on SO. But in short: If you don't declare *any* of them, all of them will be defaulted. If you declare some but not all, there are rules which cover what gets defaulted and what gets deleted.