# Disabling move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I would like to disable the move constructor in the class. Instead of moving, I would like to base on copy constructor. When I try to write this code:

```
class Boo
{
public:
    Boo(){}
    Boo(const Boo& boo) {};
    Boo(Boo&& boo) = delete;
};

Boo TakeBoo()
{
    Boo b;
    return b;
}
```

during compilation I received error:

> error C2280: 'Boo::Boo(Boo &&)': attempting to reference a deleted function

How can I disable the move constructor and force copies instead?

Comment: just don't overload the move constructor and the compiler won't generate a move constructor for it since there is already a copy constructor

Comment: From the standard: "If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if X does not have a user-declared copy constructor [...] When the move constructor is not implicitly declared or explicitly supplied, expressions that otherwise would have invoked the move constructor may instead invoke a copy constructor."

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by this? It doesn't appear to be meaningful in any way.

Comment: I'm trying to develop some micro-kernel architecture implementation using dll as modules exposing services. And the challenge is how to expose API to avoid binary compatibility problems related to different CRT (e.g debug/release) in different modules. And possibility to customize how objects are returned between dll boundaries is very useful during implementation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do not create any move constructor:

```
class Boo
{
public:
    Boo(){}
    Boo(const Boo& boo) {};
};
```

The move constructor is not automatically generated as long as a user-defined copy constructor is present so the copy constructor is called.

Comment: The move constructor is not automatically generated *if a copy constructor is present*. This is the case in the OP's example, but it's worth pointing out, lest a reader conclude that not implementing a move constructor is enough to avoid moves. For example, a class with two `std:: vector` members and no copy or move constructors implicitly defined will get an auto-generated move constructor that moves the vectors.

Answer (score 10):

Marking a function as `=delete` makes the function available for overload resolution, but if chosen, the compilation fails; this functionality is not limited to constructors and other special functions [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24676081/3747990). Previously (circa C++03) making the member private achieved a similar result.

Hence, the code as in the sample, effectively means you prohibiting the construction of an object of the class from a temporary or  expiring value (rvalues) - the move constructor.

To correct this, remove the move constructor completely. In the case of the class, once a copy constructor is present (user defined), the move is implicitly not generated anyway (move constructor and move assignment operator).

```
class Boo
{
public:
    Boo(){}
    Boo(const Boo& boo) {};
    //Boo(Boo&& boo) = delete;
};
```

Comment: Extra info: marking the move constructor as deleted yourself does indeed make it available for overload resolution; however if the move-constructor is implicitly defined as deleted (e.g. this happens if a member variable has its move constructor defined as deleted, either implicitly or explicitly) then it is *not* available for overload resolution!.    (overload resolution is fun...)